# GIT - branches not closing after merge

Tags: git, merge, git-branch

we are pretty unexperienced in using GIT. Actually we like the idea of branches ;-) But somehow all merges from one user just don't close the branch...

You can look at the image here: http://i54.tinypic.com/297i14.png

There is a grey and a blue line which just got straight forward... even after the merge... So what is he doing wrong? Any clues? I don't want imagin what happens if he creates some more branches and all of them persist in the history view even after a merge...

Thank you very much!

Comment: So what i noticed further is the following: Inspecting the commits:

Comment: So what i noticed further is the following: Inspecting the commits: THERE ARE ALWAYS 2 IDENTICAL CHILDS OR PARENTS... LIKE HERE (2x css) :

Parent: da83bd237192637ddd1824130cfafd68d8e9c352 (panda dance)
Parent: f5c6663c6248dbd79002d0b9b25423cbc90e0380 (slush puppie)
Child: 0ffa08f817ecdbe46cdffe5ae25689cb6ddcb575 (css)
Child: 0ffa08f817ecdbe46cdffe5ae25689cb6ddcb575 (css)
Child: 358034839b7f5a9f0de49b812f1f367d526b17e2 (Merge branch 'master' into trtrtr)


Actually his commits are the only ones which contain 2 dentitcal references at once... And i think this really makes no sense.

Answer (score 16):

When you do a merge, the new commit only moves forward your current branch.  The branch name that pointed to the other branch is left where it was.  In other words, if you have this situation:

```
A---B---C blue
 \
  D---E---F grey
```

... and do:

```
git checkout blue
git merge grey
```

You'll end up with:

```
A---B---C---G blue
 \         /
  D---E---F grey
```

If you want to remove the `grey` branch you can then do `git branch -d grey`.  This won't affect the commit graph, just remove the branch - they're like labels that get moved around the commit graph.

However, if you carry on and create more commits on the `grey` and `blue` branches, those lines will continue:

```
A---B---C---G---H---I blue
 \         /
  D---E---F---J---K---L grey
```

In the image you link to, I assume that either there are further commits further above the section you've shown, or the tool you're using is just presenting the commit graph strangely.

Comment: No there are no further commits in this branches... Thats the strange thing. Directly after the merge with no commit the branches from this user remain open...

Comment: In that case, what tool is it that you got that visualization from?  If you can get it to show the branch names as well, that might clear things up - branches are defined by the single commit at their tip: that commit and all its ancestors are on the branch, and anything "beyond" it isn't part of the branch.

Answer (score 3):

I am not certain what you mean by closing the branch, but I'll make a guess :)

It is still possible to use a branch even after a merge has been done. I guess this is per design and how it should be. For instance you might want to continue working with the branch even after a merge has been done, say in order to continue focusing on development in that branch. That is why it still shows up in the image you referred to.

If you don't want to do that, it is possible to delete the branch after merging, which closes it definitively by issuing the command `git branch -d <branch>` while being in another branch, like master. (This will only delete the branch if its latest commit has been merged with the branch you have active, so there is no risk of losing data.)

Comment: We will try to delete all unused branches today... But if it occures every time again i think we should reinstall Eclipse and EGit on this users computer...

Comment: Since it is per design, it will happen again. Just make a habit of deleting the branch once you've done with the merge if that is how you want it. I myself for instance have a branch for testing things out which I merge back and forth with master so there is never really a need to delete that branch. Other examples is separate branches for each developer where they do their main development (which then merges with master when they are done with one step)

Answer (score 1):

Currently git requires a two step process for the merging and closing of a 'task' branch where the merge nominally indicates closure of the task and that the branch is no longer required.

It maybe that it would be a useful option for some to be able to delete a branch's refs/heads entry so closing everything in one step [make a proposal to the git list?]. However I'm sure that many workflows have instances where they want the ability to go back and tidy up some minor issue, which an early deletion would make awkward. (though it would be in the reflog for a while)

Give the user the task of creating an alias or script to combine the two actions. It will help the education all round ;-)