# I've merged a remote branch of a git(hub) repository, but am not seeing it visualized

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, multiple-repositories

There's some github repository named foo, which both "user1" and "user2" (not me) have worked on. I have:

- forked `https://github.com/user1/foo` as `https://github.com/myself/foo`
- cloned `https://github.com/myself/foo`
- ran `git remote add user2-repo https://github.com/user2/foo` (which was a fork of an earlier version of user1/foo)
- ran `git merge user2-repo/master`
- did the merge
- committed all the changes
- git push'ed to github (to `myself/repo`)

But still, if I look at the "Network" graph - I don't see any relation between `myself/foo` and `user2/foo`; and if I use `git gui` and visualize all branches, I don't see the edge from the head of `user2-repo/master` to my `master` branch, like I expect to see according to, say, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6875714/1593077).

Is there something else I need to do? Am I not looking at the right thing? Am I misinterpreting what's supposed to happen?

Comment: who is user-2 here. Is `myself` is user-2 here?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki: No, see edit.

Comment: where did you push it `user-2/foo` or `myself/foo`

Comment: @ArpitSolanki: `myself/foo` of course, I can't push into other people's repos...

Answer (score 0):

- user2 clone user1
- me remote origin is user1
- me remote user2-repo is user2
- merging user2 to me ...

`myself` inherited only some branches, but not its remotes. This is the reason. I think repositories on github have only one remote: the one they forked from.

- myself cloned from user1
- user2 cloned from user1

myself and user are not related toghether directly. It is right.

Comment: So, you're saying only user1 merging can get the effect of the fork appearing to "go back in" on the network graph?